# Transferring Old Xbox HDD to new Xbox (No transfer Cable)

Tags: xbox-360

My old Xbox RRoD'd on me so I've gone out Xbox hunting.

I've got a new Slimline 250gb Xbox, I'm trying to get the data off my old drive on to it. I've got the old drive hooked up in a SATA Caddy so I can access it through Explorer on my PC.

I've made an image of the drive, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Anyone got any ideas? It's mainly the saved games I want over, I've formatted a USB Flash drive on the Xbox already, but it's full of Data00001 type files so I'm not sure what/if anything can be done from there.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12406/1351

Comment: I would try just copying the files to the new HDD.  XBOX 360 uses 2G archive files.

Comment: Trouble is can I even access the new hard drive? I mean I've obviously got the original Xbox 360's drive hooked up, but if I plug the SATA into the 360 it claims it needs to be optimized and I'll lose data.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two Xboxs that are hooked up to Xbox Live, you can transfer save data through the xbox.com website.

It takes a little longer but, if you have two consoles available, it's worth a try.